# ios BLE characteristic read failed - operation failed with ATT error: 0xf2

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluez

I have connected an external device with iOS peripheral application which have a BLE service with 3 characteristic.

In general it works fine, external device can send read request to specific characteristic and ios app send response properly.

But suddenly I got an issue on readRequest which I have never seen before.

When external device send read request to the same characteristic (which was working fine all the time), ios internally send operation failed response, even though the app is running. 
External device log was like:

```
 BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API: __bluetooth_internal_read_cb(906) > Error : GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Failed: Operation failed with ATT error: 0xf2
```

I didn't find any read request in ios app but ios f/w sent it internally.

As it is a reserved  ATT error, I don't know what ios defined it for.

Comment: Is your app in foreground or background?

Comment: On that time app was in background. And Background capabilities were enabled for the app. 
Is there anyway to know the reserved ATT error for iOS.
Like 0xF1, 0xF2 ..